# Find an element in array using MPI?

Tags: c++, mpi

The problem is find an element in array notifying other processors to stop.
So, if the process has found the element others must end the search.

```
.......
.......
localData = new int[sendcounts[rank]];
    MPI_Scatterv(data, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT,localData,sendcounts[rank], MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //FIND ELEMENT KEYNUMBER IN LOCALDATA
    for(int i=0;i<sendcounts[rank];i++) {
        cout<<"Index: "<<i<<endl;
        if(localData[i] == keyNumber){
            found = 1;
            //INVIA TROVATO
            for(int j=0;j<numprocs;j++){
                if(j!=rank){
                    MPI_Isend(&found,1,MPI_INT,j,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
                    cout<<"inviato"<<endl;
                }
            }
            MPI_Wait(&request,&status);
            break;
        }
        MPI_Irecv(&foundReceived,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
        cout<<"Valore Found: "<<foundReceived<<endl;
        if(foundReceived == 1){
            cout<<"si";
            break;
        }
    }
    ......
    ....
    ..
    .
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be more specific about what exactly it is you're asking. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You'll need to poll on a flag or something like that to do this async notify. Or can mpi_abort if no cleanup is required.